# Logging HTML content in a library environment with Python

Tags: python, html, logging

I have a library which third-party developers use for obtaining information off a few specific websites. The library is responsible for connecting to the website, grabbing pages, parsing necessary information, and returning it to the developer.

However, I'm having issues coming up with an acceptable way to handle storing potentially malformed `HTML`. Since I can only account for so many things when testing, parsing may fail in the future and it would be helpful if I could find a way to store the `HTML` that failed parsing for future bug fixing.

Right now I'm using the internal logging module of Python to handle logging in my library. I'm allowing the third-party developer to supply a configuration dictionary to configure how the logging outputs error data. However, printing `HTML` to the console or even to a file is to me not ideal as I think it would clutter the terminal or error log. I considered storing `HTML` files on the local hard drive, but that seems extremely intrusive.

I've determined how I'm going to pass `HTML` internally. My plan is to pass it via the parameters of an exception and then catch it with a Filter. However, what to do with it is really troubling me.

Any feedback on a method to accomplish this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Services based on websites that you don't control are likely to be somewhat fragile, so storing the HTML to avoid recrawling in the event of parsing problems makes perfect sense to me. Since uncompressed HTML can consume a lot of space on the disk, you might want to store it in a compressed form in a database.

I've found MongoDB to be convenient for this. The underlying storage format is BSON (i.e. binary JSON). It's also easy to install and use.

Here's a toy example using PyMongo to store this page in MongoDB:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import urllib2
import time

# what will be stored in the document
ts = time.time()
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683772/logging-html-content-in-a-library-environment-with-python'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

# create a dict and store it in MongoDB
htmlDict = {'url':url, 'ts':ts, 'html':html}
client = MongoClient()
db = client.html_log
collection = db.html
collection.insert(htmlDict)
```

Check to see that the document is stored in MongoDB:

```
$ mongo
> use html_log;
> db.html.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54544d96164a1b22d3afd887"), "url" : "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26683772/logging-html-content-in-a-library-environment-with-python", "html" : "<!DOCTYPE html> [...] </html>", "ts" : 1414810778.001168 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's the difference between this and just zipping up an html file? Adding another dependency to my library also isn't too ideal.

Comment: I agree that it might not make sense for you. Here's why I might do this in a similar situation: let's suppose I collected a lot of data and needed to re-parse quickly (i.e. on a cluster). The gzip solution would either create a lot of files (which can be problematic), or very large gzip files that cannot be processed in 'chunks' without decompressing the whole files first. The 'stuff it in Mongo just-in-case' approach leaves you an easy path to re-processing on a cluster (e.g. perhaps using mongo-hadoop) with a minimal amount of change to your Python code.